How to use LAG function on multiple rows
Input data



player_id
team_ranking
price_money




131
9
100


289
9
100


83
9
100


236
8
200


154
8
200


230
7
300


72
7
300


200
6
400


174
6
400


326
6
400


261
6
400


60
5
500


181
5
500


387
5
500


34
4
600


144
4
600


377
3
700


222
3
700


112
3
700


16
2
800


36
2
800


299
1
1000



Output I want is :



player_id
team_ranking
price_money




131
9
0


289
9
0


83
9
0


236
8
100


154
8
100


230
7
200


72
7
200


200
6
300


174
6
300


326
6
300


261
6
300


60
5
400


181
5
400


387
5
400


34
4
500


144
4
500


377
3
600


222
3
600


112
3
600


16
2
700


36
2
700


299
1
800



However when I try to use lag. It seems like it is only moving 1 persons price money from each team down.
I am trying to use lag functions over each teams ranking and shift each teams price money down by 1.
How do I do this.I tried with below code and got output as below :
SELECT Player_id, Team_Ranking,
  LAG(Price_Money, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Team_Ranking desc) AS Price_Money FROM table;




Player_id
Team_Ranking
Price_Money




289
9
0


83
9
100


131
9
100


236
8
100


154
8
200


230
7
200


72
7
300


200
6
300


174
6
400


326
6
400


261
6
400


60
5
400


387
5
500


181
5
500


34
4
500


144
4
600


377
3
600


222
3
700


112
3
700


16
2
700


36
2
800


299
1
800




Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?, and Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?

Also specifying [tag:mysql] AND [tag:oracle-database] is never correct, Specify only the DBMS that you are using.

Please read the paragraph "Introduce the problem before you post any code" (on How to ask)


As mentioned in the comments above please do not use images for input and output data,rather use sample input and output in tabular markdown format. Also I am not sure whether you want mysql or oracle since both are tagged, I have used mysql as an example.

As you want to apply lag on a team ranking but in your final table you have multiple columns of same team rank. To achieve this I have created a cte with team_ranking and price_money, used lag to get the desired result and joined it back to the final table


Fiddle
with distinct_team_ranking_money as
  (
select 
  Team_Ranking, 
   LAG(Price_Money, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY Team_Ranking desc) AS price_money
from 
(SELECT 
   distinct 
    Team_Ranking, 
   price_money from test
  ) as  T
  )

select test.player_id, test.team_ranking, distinct_team_ranking_money.price_money
from 
test
  
left join distinct_team_ranking_money
  on distinct_team_ranking_money.Team_Ranking = test.Team_Ranking ; 

Output



player_id
team_ranking
price_money




131
9
0


289
9
0


83
9
0


236
8
100


154
8
100


230
7
200


72
7
200


200
6
300


174
6
300


326
6
300


261
6
300


60
5
400


181
5
400


387
5
400


34
4
500


144
4
500


377
3
600


222
3
600


112
3
600


16
2
700


36
2
700


299
1
800



